# Loading/Parsing Mathematical Programming System files

Tags: python, python-2.7, linear-programming, mps

In order not to reinvent the wheel I tried to find some code to parse
 [Mathematical Programming System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPS_(format)) files but I didnt find any implementations in python.

[image]

Is there any code allready available for this?

> Update

Reading [Mathematical Prog. files](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_adv/usr_cut_lazy_constr/11_rw_MPS_files.html)

Example MPS (afiro.mps: [link1](https://projects.coin-or.org/OS/browser/trunk/OS/data/afiro.mps?rev=1), [link2](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/mps/afiro.mps))
Contains:

1. objective function, one row, n columns
2. table with restrictions, m rows, n columns
3. right table, one column, m rows

Many [languages have packages](https://rweb.stat.umn.edu/R/site-library/linprog/html/readMps.html) for reading and writing these files.

Comment: And what's the expected output of the parser?

Comment: Load the tables in 3 arrays

Comment: Not many LP/MIP solvers are written in Python (for performance reasons).

Comment: It makes perfect sense Erwin.

Comment: I'll probably change the project requirements

Comment: Parsing the MPS file and solving the system are different problems. I think that parsing that should be easy with Python + PLY, but I could not guess exactly what are the 3 arrays that you want. I could have a try if you give me the exact result on this example.

Comment: Indeed no conceptual reason to have the MPS reader "close" to the solver. In practice, most solvers have MPS readers built-in. MPS files can become very large and we want to read these very fast and produce immediately a data structure (sparse matrix) suited for the solver (column wise storage of the nonzeros).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen many languages have packages for reading and writing these files. But I cannot find anything for python.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I think it may be a little bit hard to make a parser for this, if there is a package for it, it would be way better

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for libraries is explicitely off topic on SO. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*

Comment: Yes, I know, I want to parse this and I just said that other languages have libraries, it would be great if python had one but it does not in my knowledge. So if anyone has /knows a code for this it would be great.

Comment: I will close this question Serge in a day or two if no one knows a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not address the specifics, e.g. pure python vs. c-wrapper-based, nor any license-issues.

But well... two things which worked for me in the past (the former was more tested for my own IPM-method on the netlib dataset; the latter looked good too):

[Dirty code](https://github.com/sschnug/scipy_lp_dev) to use netlib's test cases with scipy's solvers based on the former approach.

#### cvxopt

MPS-reading is somewhat hidden [here](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/modeling.html) and [here](https://github.com/cvxopt/cvxopt/blob/4e9e75fc4f4b8852b0c9af9b3dc56a2d11310751/src/python/modeling.py#L2762).

Looks pretty much python-only to me.

One should be careful about potentially modifications already done to the problem by cvxopt, at least when asking cvxopt for the matrix-form. I don't remember right now what to expect here (and it also did not matter much in my cases).

Warning: cvxopt is known for a non-trivial installation-process on windows, if you try to install the whole project!

There are also some warnings about what features of MPS-files are not supported.

#### GLPK + swiglpk

Basically swig-based bindings for GLPK. Available [here](https://github.com/biosustain/swiglpk) (probably most newest python-bindings to GLPK). If using this, use it together with GLPK's manual and some understanding of [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) (or [else](https://github.com/biosustain/swiglpk/issues/19) ).

This one should be more controllable in terms of what we read (see manual)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pysmps](https://pypi.org/project/pysmps/) package in Python. It can simply be installed through `pip install pysmps`. Further details can be found in:

> https://pypi.org/project/pysmps/
>
> https://github.com/jmaerte/pysmps